# Raycast drawing and hitting limited to inside cylinder

Tags: unity, physics, raycasting, meshcollider

I'm trying to get a very basic "radar" system to work. Right now, I'm not even scanning, just looking at a known target location.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RadarScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject radar;
    public GameObject target;

    private bool found = false;

    void Update () {

        Vector3 lookLocation = target.transform.position - radar.transform.position;

        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (found == false) {

            Ray ray = new Ray (radar.transform.position, lookLocation);

            Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hitInfo, 10000.0f, 0)) {
                if (hitInfo.collider.tag == "Target") {

                    printHitInfo (hitInfo);

                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printHitInfo(RaycastHit hit) {
        Debug.Log ("TARGET FOUND!");
        Debug.Log ("Distance: " + hit.distance);
    }
}
```

So, here's the result can be seen here: https://gfycat.com/FloweryBraveCockroach

There's 2 problems here.

1. The Debug.DrawRay call is only drawing the ray **inside** the cylinder (radar).
2. The target is never being hit.

What's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Direction** is always a **normalized vector**. If you assign a vector of non unit length, it will be normalized.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray-direction.html

So `Debug.DrawRay` call is only drawing normalized vector.

```
Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);
```

this Is mean you used normalized vector Instead of self vector:

```
Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin,lookLocation.normalized, Color.red);
```

try this it should work:

```
Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin,lookLocation, Color.red);
```

[image]

**Next problem**:The target is never being hit.

because you used [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) in the last parameter

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hitInfo, 10000.0f, ⚠️0 (LayerMask)⚠️)
```

you can replace **0** by **1** it will work.but you don't need **LayerMask** here remove it like this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hitInfo, 10000.0f)
```